# How phpMyAdmin connect to mySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not with connection problems with phpMyAdmin. My problem is about my own scripts for connection with mySQL server. I do it like the manual says:

```
new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```

However, if the server is down, the script hangs at this point, until a timeout error. This don't happens when I try to open phpMyAdmin, it returns me an error at once (#2002). I wish to do the same with my code, implement a escape from timeout error and error handling. I was thinking about to look inside phpMyAdmin code and see how they did, but since it's support is here and this might be a useful information for other developers (not because I'm lazy), I decided to ask a question.

So, any clues? Event handling? Some asynchronous technique?

Comment: Your first reaction was correct. Look into the code.

Comment: Instead of answering this, I will second @Michi's advice. Look into the phpMyAdminCode !

Comment: Ok, I'll pretend you know the answer but wish to see me work... Never mind, I'll ask myself and earn the points to my reputation.

Comment: Is the second time I try to explore this subject here, with low results. This time, with tips from idipous and Marc Delisle, I could made a code with similar result as phpMyAdmin, we are getting closer. I still think we should investigate how exactly this software do the job so well, but it seams I'm not good enough for leading the discussion (I'm been serious now). Looking the code make me learn a lot, to bad we can't go on. Better luck next time...

Answer (score 1):

Without me looking at the PhPMyAdmin code, I would suggest setting the mysqli timeout as low as needed.

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1)
```

However, I would still look to PhPMyAdmin just in case they have a better solution.

Comment: I'm testing this option, but it seams not been used in phpMyAdmin. Still looking...

Comment: This way works, but you should also use "@" in the command line so it will not be written warning messages (I'm testing procedural way so far because it's the way phpMyAdmin does). However, I didn't find this setting in the code... it's a mystery!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your phpMyAdmin is configured to use the mysqli extension. In the current 4.0.8 version, look in libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php in the functions PMA_DBI_connect() and PMA_DBI_real_connect()

Comment: You know, I don't know if is using mysqli. I have 3.3 version, but there is the files you mention, I'm looking it now.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin's main page, look for "PHP extension".

Answer (score 0):

this is the coorect format of sql connection in localhost

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Error in connection! ");
?>
```

now it looks like your assigning variables to it if thats the case do it like this

```
$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
password="";

<?php
$con = mysql_connect('$hostname','$username','$password') or die("Error in connection! ");
?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, will stop working soon, we should use mysqli.